# First Rails Configuration from Lynda.com tutorial, can't launch using rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i tried rails server I got:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/inathan/sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

I thought I followed the steps verbatim, but now I'm stumped.  Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql from mysql official site, make sure it is started and then install appropriate mysql gem (mysql for rails 2.x and mysql2 for rails 3.x)